# Recreate Doors of Durin's text in 3d but fonts are messed up

Tags: text-object, font

I'm working on a personal project in 3d. And I wanted to recreate in 3d, the text we can see on the Doors of Durin.

I use the original text in Sindarin "Ennyn Durin aran Moria pedo mellon a minno".

https://glaemscrafu.jrrvf.com/french/glaemscribe.html?mode=sindarin-tengwar-beleriand

I use Blender, and when I copy and past the text, with Tengwar Annatar font, it doesn't match the real transcription and text.

I don't want to waste time on matching every characters.

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sadly not a Blender Question.

Your downloaded font needs to match the font used in the website. Open the developer options and go to the network tab, then reload the site. It shows which font files are fetched. Right click the *tengwar-annatar-glaemuicode* font and choose *Open in New Tab* to download it.

[image: fonts fetched]

I copy paste the glyphs from your translation site.

[image: copy the selected text.]

Using the correct font you can paste the letters in Blender.

[image: font in blender]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the font files. But when I write "Ennyn Durin aran Moria", the output doesn't match the real characters. Like the letter E doesn't match with E but with L, etc...

Comment: I used this website, to match the actual characters. https://www.tolkiendil.com/langues/ecritures/tengwar/correspondance_clavier_tengwar

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I copied.

Comment: @SamihELSAKHAWI Don't know about the website you used to match the characters, but if you take a look at the original inscription instead of what this overview for the single letters says, it is absolutely correct that the 'e' looks like the 'l' on that other website: [Doors of Durin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj9yX.jpg). The only difference is that the inscription looks more hand-written than a computer font.

Answer (score 1):

This is a font issue, not really related to Blender.

Glaemscribe uses its own font encoding, incompatible with most other fonts. Consider using [BSScribe](http://blackspeech.ru/transcriber/) or [Tecendil](https://www.tecendil.com/) instead.

Note that there are two different font encodings: an old encoding to ASCII based on the QWERTY keyboard layout, and a more modern Unicode-based one, using the Private Use Area. When copying the text, be sure to set the transcription to the font you wish to use.